# Is it possible to only sync favorite photos/videos to iCloud from my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

So, I've accumulated a lot of photos and videos on my iPhone and I'm happy to sync a few to iCloud, but I don't really want all of them there. Partially because there are lots of near-duplicates and also because I don't have enough space in iCloud.

Instead, I would like to ONLY sync favorites to iCloud and not bother with the non-favorites. Any ideas on how to do so?

iPhone 6
iOS 10.1.1

Answer (score 4):

No, but it's possible using Apple's iCloud Drive.
*With iCloud Drive, you can safely store all your presentations, spreadsheets, PDFs, **images** and any other kind of document in iCloud — and access them from your iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, Mac or PC.*

**Following are the steps to upload your favourite pics on iCloud:**

**Step 1:** Open your favourite photo from photos app which you would like to upload on iCloud.

**Step 2:** After opening it, go to options

[image]

**Step 3:** Select **Add to iCloud Drive** option

[image]

**Step 4:** Select iCloud drive from the list. If you want to save your photo inside a folder present in the iCloud drive, choose that. For example, here if I want to save the photo in *AI T2* folder I can choose that by tapping on it.

[image]

Here's the pic after upload:

[image]

**NOTE**

Make sure you have **iCloud Drive** app on your iPhone. If you don't have it then go to the App Store and search for *iCloud Drive*. Since, you are on iOS 10 you can download Apple's builtin apps from App Store (and delete them too). If this doesn't work, Go to Settings -> iCloud -> iCloud Drive -> Switch *Show on Home Screen* to On.

Here's the iCloud Drive app on the homescreen.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't do what the original question asked, since it doesn't automatically upload the pictures in the favorites folder. You can still select them one by one, but this would be impractical for someone who has hundreds of "favorites" in their gallery.

Comment: +1 to Reubend, this totally misses the point of the question. Ccan't tell if kshikhar doesn't know what the "favorites" feature (heart icon) is or is ignoring it, but the point is to have that set of files automatically synced and available on all devices while relegating the rest to long-term storage in Photos app on Mac

Comment: @jerclarke It's a workaround.

Comment: It’s probably the best possible answer, but should be mildly edited to open “No, but...” instead of “Yes, it’s possible...”

Comment: @WiseOldDuck thanks for inputs - edited my response :)